# Use jars from ivy cache

Tags: ant, ivy

Is it possible to prevent ivy from copying jars to project directory and instead generate classpath that refers directly to files in ivy cache ?

Comment: David W's example also contains the use of an ivy configuration to cotnrol which jars appear on the classpath. Another example of how to use configurations (This posting is a follow-up to your question on the ivy retrieve task).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `<ivy:cachepath/>` task to create your classpath without copying the jars into your project:

```
 <target name="compile">

    <!-- Create a classpath reference for my compile -->
    <ivy:cachepath pathid="main.classpath"
        conf="compile"/>

    <!-- Compile using my classpath reference-->    
    <javac srcdir="${main.srcdir}"
        destdir="${main.destdir}"
        classpathref="main.classpath"/>

</target>
```